# Run Windows Server Task Scheduler task M-F EXCEPT on 1st of month

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008-r2

I currently have a task that runs every Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday and Friday of every week.

I also have a task that runs every Sunday.

I need the task that runs every Sunday to also run on the first of every month.

I can create a new task that runs the "Sunday-action" on the first of every month however I can not find a way to make the other tasks NOT run on the first of the month while keeping their normal schedule.

I need a way to run something that will disable those tasks on the first of the month (and then re-enable them for the next day) or a way to add additional conditions to have them not run on certain days that their original condition would have them normally run.